# Javascript [jQuery 1.9.1] getting the id of the parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<div id="myImages">
    <div id="file_50" class="file_bg">
        <span id="button_remove" class="files">Remove Image</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the id of the div that holds the span `.files`, so I get the id `#file_50`
What i've tried:

```
console.log("Sent id: " + $(this).parent().attr('id'));
```

This attempt is getting the id of the first div, `#myImages`

```
console.log("Sent id: " + $(this).parent().find(".file_bg").attr('id'));
```

Just a guess, but it is returning undefined.

**how can I do this?**

Comment: You're not showing us the event firing, and therefore what `this` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work is because when you use parent() you get to the object you want then you are using find which searches descendants. It's enough to use `parent()` or just `closest()`

Try this, use closest()

```
console.log("Sent id: " + $(this).closest('div.file_bg').attr('id'))
```

or just `closest('div')` like this

```
console.log("Sent id: " + $(this).closest('div').attr('id'))
```

or just .parent()

```
console.log("Sent id: " + $(this).parent().attr('id'))
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/ALzFt/)

```
 $('.files').on('click', function () {
     console.log("Sent id: " + $(this).parent().attr('id'))
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
alert("Sent id: " + $(".files").parent().attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log("Sent id: " + $(this).parent()[0].id);
```

and

```
console.log("Sent id: " + $(this).parent().find(".file_bg")[0].id);
```

Attention in second case, i am using an array because `.attr` might give you a array of id's.